# Running qtfaststart in a folder containing multiple .mp4's

Tags: bash, video, terminal, video-streaming, h.264

I have a library of videos, all of which need to be adjusted for web-streaming by putting the moov atom ahead of the rest of the video with [`qtfaststart`](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart). This allows playback to begin before the client has completely downloaded the video.

How can I do this? Should I run a .sh script directed to that folder to run `qtfaststart`? If so, how would such a script look like?

Comment: Best and easiest according to what criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
for f in *.mp4; do qtfaststart "$f"; done
```

This works because `qtfaststart` will overwrite the input file automatically.

If you want this done recursively, you could use `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec qtfaststart {} \;
```

Or with shell globs (e.g. in Bash 4):

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.mp4; do qtfaststart "$f"; done
```

Comment: is there a way of making this recursive for subfolders?

Comment: See my updated answer.